# I need send copied text in telegram bot using selenium-chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, telegram-bot

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='span12']")
    # send the copied text back 
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=element)
```

#come error

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='span12']")
2021-10-15 05:34:51,229 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception
........................
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type WebElement is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: `JSON` can send only primitive types of data but you have object `WebElement`. You should manually convert it to string `text=str(element`)` but probably you should use `.text` to get text from this object. `text=element.text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
Add the following line to your code:

```
content = browser.find_element_by_id('report').text
```

Full example:

```
content = browser.find_element_by_id('report').text

# send the copid text back
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=content)
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` can send only primitive types of data but you have object `WebElement`.

You should manually convert it to string

```
send_message(..., text=str(element) )
```

but probably you simply forgot `.text` to get text from this object.

```
send_message(..., text=element.text )
```

Comment: can add  it's working  `content = browser.find_element_by_id('report').text

    # send the copid text back
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=content)`

Comment: Thanks bro reply me